# rename tmux window name to prompt_command, ps1 or remote ssh hostname?

Tags: tmux

I would love to be able to have my tmux window title automatically renamed to prompt_command, ps1 or just the hostname of a machine I `ssh` to. having 9 windows opened labeled "ssh" is really useless. Doing sysadmin work I open new screens and ssh around to much to manually rename them.

One thing I noticed is `tmux` updates the `xterm` window title so I feel like it has to know.

Any help? I would even be willing to go back to `screen` if I could get this feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to make it look at your `PS1` directly.

However, `tmux` understands the same commands to set the window name as `screen` does.

So you can define a function like this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
settitle() {
    printf "\033k$1\033\\"
}
```

and then call `settitle` from anywhere.

For example, you could include it in your `PS1` variable, e.g.

```
PS1='$HOST:$PWD$(settitle $HOST:$PWD)$ '
```

or via `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='$(settitle $HOST:$PWD)'
# and don't change PS1
```

---

Now I understand you have `tmux` running on your desktop, and you want `ssh` commands to have the hostname rather than `ssh`, that's much easier.

Given you've added `settitle` to your local `~/.bashrc`, all you want to do is add this too:

```
ssh() {
    settitle "$*"
    command ssh "$@"
    settitle "bash"
}
```

Replace bash with zsh, or something else more appropriate if necessary.

Comment: This really dont name the window title to the hostname of remote box with out having the .bashrc setup on the remote box. Thank you though I did learn some slick.

Comment: If all you want is the hostname on your local side, that's much easier.  Hang on a sec...

Comment: brilliant! thank you. Sorry my inability to explain my request resulted in two questions. again, Thanks!

Comment: As tmux changes its window title on a whim, this can very quickly be overwritten by normal changes to the window title by tmux.

Comment: Thanks! I used `PROMPT_COMMAND='settitle $HOSTNAME:$PWD'` - since with @Mikel's code I got no hostname and a `-bash: : No such file or directory` error before each command prompt. It seems to me that the `$()` would make bash try to execute whatever `settitle` *returns*. (I'm running bash on linux.)

Answer (score 43):

`tmux rename-window -t${TMUX_PANE} "Title Text"`

This is the proper way to set tmux titles in a window.  The $TMUX_PANE variable is set by tmux and is used to differentiate between different panes.

Comment: As it's the active window, I don't think the `-t${TMUX_PANE}` is necessary (at least it wasn't for me).

Comment: @Christopher If you're running, say, `sleep 3` and switch windows, the prompt would otherwise issue the command to the wrong window when sleep completes. (This is the reason I came here, +1).

Answer (score 20):

Just for people who came here by searching how to change the title of a tmux session:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>

This will give you a prompt, where you can rename the active session.

To change the active window use komma instead:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>

see: [How do I rename a session in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/428016/how-do-i-rename-a-session-in-tmux)

Comment: Exactly, what I was searching for. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Combining both Mikel's and UtahJarhead's answers, I used the following in `.zshrc` to solve this problem:

```
ssh() {
    tmux rename-window "$*"
    command ssh "$@"
    exit
}
```

I have automatic window renaming enabled by default, and I can't find a way to reenable it after exiting the remote host. Thus, I just exit the window entirely -- not an issue for my workflow. If you'd prefer to rename it to, say, 'bash', you could replace the `exit` line with `tmux rename-window "bash"`.

Comment: I am using tmux rename-window `hostname -s` after the command ssh "@$", it basically "resets" the title to my "gateway" machine.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `exit` or `tmux rename-window "bash"` you can use

```
ssh() {
    if [ "$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=)" = "tmux" ]; then
            tmux rename-window "$*"
            command ssh "$@"
            tmux set-window-option automatic-rename "on" 1>/dev/null
    else
            command ssh "$@"
    fi
}
```

This re-activates the normal function that renames automatically window for next commands.

The `if` block prevents from (without it) renaming `tmux` current window from `ssh` commands used on other shells (out of `tmux`).

Comment: I've gone for a `if env | grep -q "TMUX_PANE"; then` instead of the `ps -p...` stuff, but same principle.

Comment: Most common shells have `$PPID` defined, FWIW.  But I prefer to use `[[ -n "${TMUX_PANE:-}" ]]` as the test - that way the whole test is done with string comparison builtins; no fork or subshell required. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered a long time ago, but I thought I would add what I have fiddled with and found (based on the accepted answer).. I have added this to the /etc/bashrc of all my servers (easy to do with fabric, puppet, etc)

```
settitle() {
    printf "\033k$1\033\\"
}
bash_prompt_command() {
    settitle "`hostname -s`:$PWD"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=bash_prompt_command
```

And it sets the window name automatically in screen or tmux.

Comment: we use internal dns, so `hostname -s` removes the extra domain stuff, so that server1.internal.local shows up as just server1

Comment: It's ideal to always use `hostname -s` and `hostname -f` if you want just the short or fully-qualified hostnames, respectively.  So, thumbs-up for that part.  Though, technically `man(1) hostname` (see the FILES section) and `man(5) hostname` both indicate that there should probably not be periods in the contents of /etc/hostname. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would note in all of these examples with:

```
command ssh "$@"
```

You might want to grab the exitcode, and exit the function with it, otherwise things like:

```
ssh server false
```

Will return 0.

```
command ssh"$@"
_exitcode=$?
#other code
exit $_exitcode
```

Will exit ssh with the return code of the ssh.

Comment: Very helpful note!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to rename the active window to its previous name, after the ssh session :

```
ssh() {

local code=0
local ancien

ancien=$(tmux display-message -p '#W')

if [ $TERM = tmux -o $TERM = tmux-256color ]; then

    tmux rename-window "$*"

    command ssh "$@"

    code=$?
else
    command ssh "$@"

    code=$?
fi

tmux rename-window $ancien

return $code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for in `tmux 2.1` and with zsh locally and on servers:

```
ssh() {
    tmux set-option allow-rename off 1>/dev/null
    tmux rename-window "ssh/$*"
    command ssh "$@"
    tmux set-option allow-rename on 1>/dev/null
}
```

I had to disable the allow-rename option manually before changing the windows name - otherwise it got changed to the current path on most of my servers (also using zsh there). The good thing is: if you reenable the allow-rename option it works immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.profile` or `.bashrc`

```
# Change window name for `tmux`
ssh() {
    if [ "$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=)" = "tmux" ]; then
        #tmux rename-window "$(echo $* | cut -d . -f 1)"
        tmux rename-window "$(echo $* | cut -d @ -f 2)"
        command ssh "$@"
        tmux set-window-option automatic-rename "on" 1>/dev/null
    else
        command ssh "$@"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a (callback) function to set/restore tmux window name like this, the default name here to restore is `bash`.

```bsh
set_tmux_window_name()
{
    [[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && return
    [[ -z "$1" ]] && tmux rename-window "bash" || tmux rename-window $1
}
```

and then create a ssh wrapper which will restore the tmux window name back to `bash` as you defined once the ssh wrapper exited due to signals like KILL/TERM/ABORT/..

```bsh
ssh_wrapper ()
{ 
    trap set_tmux_window_name SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGILL SIGABRT SIGEMT SIGFPE SIGKILL SIGBUS SIGSEGV SIGTERM

    ssh_cmd=$@
    [[ "$ssh_cmd" = "" ]] && return
    eval $ssh_cmd
}
```

now set the tmux window name before setting up the ssh connection

```bsh
alias ssh1='set_tmux_window_name "ssh1"; ssh_wrapper username@hostname'
```