# Tmux and ZSH custom prompt : bug with window name

Tags: git, zsh, tmux, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I have customized my ZSH prompt with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) to make it more readable and add information about git if I'm in a repository.

Example :
`bob@inf [~/docs] %`
`bob@inf [~/src/nicest] master %` (in a git repository)

It works well but I have some bugs with `tmux` and the window name. It still display non sense value and I cannot disable it with `automatic-rename off` (it just do not work, the window name change after each command), for the first example tmux use `~/docs` for the window name.

I'm not sure how I can fix it, I would like to keep my zsh prompt as it is, if can make change but would like to understand where is the problem ?

Another solution may be to redefine command `settile` (from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/249293/rename-tmux-window-name-to-prompt-command-ps1-or-remote-ssh-hostname/249322#249322)) but I'm not sure how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I took a peek at oh-my-zsh and found a [likely suspect](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh).

When the value of the TERM environment variable starts with `screen` (which it should under both *screen* and *tmux*), it uses a *screen* terminal control sequence to set the window’s name to

- (just before displaying a shell prompt)
  the left-most portion of the “tilde compressed” path of the current working directory (`..` followed by the last 13 characters or the entire path if it less than 15 characters) and
- (just before starting a command)
  the first “word” of about-to-be-run command (not counting `ssh`, `sudo`, and a few others).

It sounds like it is working this way for you (you said that your window named changed to `~/docs` when you were in that directory). If you want to disable this automatic renaming, you can can disable it completely by setting the DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE shell parameter to `true` in your `.zshrc`:

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true
```

If you just set this in an interactive shell, you will end up with an empty string for the current window’s name, but oh-my-zsh will stop updating the window before each prompt and command in that shell instance (it needs to be in your `.zshrc` to affect all new shell instances).

Comment: This is such a perfect answer. Accurate, informative, concise and to the point. Moreover, it provides a solution in addition to answering the original question ("understanding where is the problem").It's only sad that whoever took the time to ask didn't bother marking this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you

Comment: where is a `.zshrc` file for all users?

Answer (score 32):

I know that the answer above gives you a solution, but another one is to simply add this option your the ~/.tmux.conf

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

Comment: This is a better solution since it only affects tmux.

Comment: Even with this setting, join-pane followed by break-pane resets the window name :(

Answer (score 6):

I met the same issue, which is tmux's window name was changed even by setting in .tmux.conf:

```
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
```

Thanks Chris's answer. My tmux window name wasn't renamed automatically after I changed:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

to:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the automatic-rename only for certain window then you can use:

```
 set -t [WINDOW_NUMBER] automatic-rename off
```

Disable the automatic-rename in specific window in another session:

```
 set -t [SESSION]:[WINDOW_NUMBER] automatic-rename off
```