# Can I set a default title for a tmux window?

Tags: tmux

Right now the title defaults to `reattach-to-user-namespace` (OS X), which is pretty annoying.
Is there an option I can put into my `tmux.conf` to get another default title?

If not, how would I make a key binding that creates a new window and then prompts me for a name?

Comment: See answer here http://superuser.com/questions/306028/tmux-and-zsh-custom-prompt-bug-with-window-name

Comment: That's about disabling automatic renaming (which I already did), not about default names, right?

Comment: I guess you're right, sorry!

Comment: I use `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"`, and most of the time end up with a window named `zsh`, as desired. For unknown reasons, sometimes the name doesn't switch, and the window is called `reattach-to-user-namespace`. I still haven't noticed a pattern as to when/why this happens, but it seems like there might be a subtle bug, or something in my configuration.

Comment: What is the best way to put the window number in the name?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no global default window name that is applied to all new windows; they default to (part of) the first “word” of the command (or the default shell if there is no command). Your windows are probably defaulting to `reattach-to-user-namespace` because you that is the first interesting bit of your `default-command` value.

It would be a bit round-about, but you could put your default command in a shell script and point your `default-command` to that script instead. With that configuration the default window name (for windows created without an explicit command) would be whatever you named the shell script.

Otherwise, there are several ways to manually name/rename a window:

- At creation time with `-n`:

  ```
  new-window -n 'some name'
  ```

  You could re-bind `c` (the default key used to create a window) to incorporate a “default name” of your choosing:

  ```
  bind-key c new-window -n 'default name'
  ```
- Rename an existing window:

  ```
  rename-window 'new name'
  ```

  There is also a default binding (Prefix `,`) that will prompt you for a new name and rename the window.
- Rename a window via an “escape sequence” sent to a pane’s tty:

  ```
  # E.g. in a shell:
  printf '\033kWINDOW_NAME\033\\'
  ```

Your “prompt me for a name for a new window” can be done like this (prompting before or after creating the window):

```
bind-key C command-prompt -p "Name of new window: " "new-window -n '%%'"

bind-key C new-window \; command-prompt -p "Name for this new window: " "rename-window '%%'"
```

Comment: Wow, this is a really epic answer, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I found a way to set a default title: `set-option -g default-command "tmux rename-window base; reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"` sets a default title of `base`. You might want to add this to your answer. :)

Comment: your solution breaks tmux managers like tmuxinator. In that case, the tabs do not get renamed

Answer (score 4):

tmux picks the first command as the window name.

Say you want "i" to be the default title, you can trick it like this.

```
set-option -g default-command "i > /dev/null 2>&1; reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

This is better than

```
set-option -g default-command "tmux rename-window i; reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"
```

because if you create a pane after you manually set a window title, the title will be renamed back to "i" again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Chris' answer on setting the window title using `new window -n 'somename'`, you can also provide an empty string `''` as the name of a window. This way, I can use the default shortcut (prefix + c) and do not need to come up with a name for temporary windows, but can still rename them when neccessary:

`bind-key c new-window -n ''`

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer more than a hack:

I created a symlink with

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/reattach-to-user-namespace /usr/local/bin/pbash`

And now it shows as `pbash` as the default title.