# Tmux New Window Default Name

Tags: tmux

I'm using tmux on Fedora 20 (I installed the default tmux rpm using yum). When I create a new window inside tmux, the default title is something like this:

```
user@hoest:/path/to/this/folder
```

which is pretty long and annoying to change. I found some potential solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/565464/can-i-set-a-default-title-for-a-tmux-window), but none of them seem to work in my case. Any hint on how I can solve this?

Here is my `~/.tmux.conf`

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind a send-prefix
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g base-index 1
set -g pane-base-index 1
bind-key c new-window -n "default"
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-left '#[fg=green]#H'
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg red
set -g status-right '#[fg=yellow]#(uptime | cut -d "," -f 4-)'
setw -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g history-limit 100000
set-option -g default-shell /usr/bin/bash
set -sg escape-time 1
```

Comment: Probably something in your shell configuration (part of PS1 or via PROMPT_COMMAND?) is using an escape sequence to set the window title.

Comment: Well I checked both of them (changed PS1 and also unset PROPMT_COMMAND) without luck. One thing that I noticed was that the when I change to a dir in tmux, it updates the window title. I tried to set `set-window-option -g automatic-rename off` but it didn't work either. I found [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=969429#c5) bug, which is related to PROPMT_COMMAND, but not directly related to my case I guess.

Comment: So, check for an alias or shell function that is covering `cd`? `type cd`

Comment: `type cd` didn't return anything. However, I finally was able to sort of bypass the problem by using `set-option -g allow-rename off`. Thanks for taking time to give hints.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same issue on Fedora 20. This is apparently due to the change of the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable that was reported in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=969429.

This is the workaround I'm using:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/true /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
```

This will prevent `/etc/bashrc` from setting a `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable that sets the window title to a very long value when using screen or tmux.