# Setting the first window defualt name when initiating a tmux session

Tags: tmux

Looking at [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/565741), I was able to default new windows names to '' by adding

```
bind c new-window -n ''
```

to the `.tmux.conf` file. It works for new windows during a session, but when starting a new tmux session with the `tmux` command, the first window still has the default name.

Answer (score 0):

> when starting a new tmux session with the `tmux` command, the first window still has the default name.

The manual states:

> If no commands are specified, the `new-session` command is assumed.

So bare `tmux` is equivalent to `tmux new-session`. You need it to be `tmux new-session -n ''`.

---

Create a wrapper script or a shell function that will pass the long command instead of sole `tmux`. Example function:

```
tmux () {
   if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
      then command tmux new-session -n ''
      else command tmux "$@"
   fi
   }
```

Note this simple approach will "fix" bare `tmux` but not e.g. `tmux -S foo`. Adding logic in order to properly identify all such cases may not be trivial.

Comment: Another approach would be to rename windows as soon as they are created. I experimented with hooks but haven't got firm results yet.