# Make tmux window names use bash $PS1

Tags: bash, tmux

On Windows, connecting to `tmux` 1.8 on CentOS 7 through MobaXterm.

Ideally, I want my tmux windows to have the name of the last command that I typed in whichever pane is active (like, `cd /home` not `bash` like `{pane_current_command}` prints). I have no idea how to do that, so instead I'm trying to find out how to get the name match the `PS1` of the active pane. I tried [the suggestions in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/249293/rename-tmux-window-name-to-prompt-command-ps1-or-remote-ssh-hostname) with this in my bashrc:

```
settitle() {
    printf "\033k$1\033\\"
}
basic_prompt='${USER:0:3}@${PWD:${#PWD}<15?0:(-15)}'
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ((counter++)); else counter=0; fi; settitle($basic_prompt)'
PS1='(\[\e[4m\]${USER:0:3}\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[34m\]${PWD:${#PWD}<15?0:(-15)}\[\e[m\])[$counter]\\$ '
```

and got

`bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token '$basic_prompt'`

1. Is there any way to name a tmux window by the last completed command?
2. If not, how can I correctly get it to set to my `PS1`, which is dynamic based on my username and path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved for tmux 2.6 and tmux 1.8 (tested on both).

To have `tmux` display a dynamic window title, edit your `~/.bashrc` to something similar to the following:

```
settitle() {
    printf "\033k$1\033\\"
}
dynamic_window_title='${USER:0:3}@${PWD:${#PWD}<25?0:(-25)}'
PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ "$TERM" =~ "screen" ]; then eval prompt=$dynamic_window_title; settitle "$prompt"; fi;'
```

And you'll (probably) need you `~/.tmux.conf` to have:

```
setw -g automatic-rename on
```

As I understand it, `settitle()` is basically renaming your window after every command you execute. I don't fully understand how it does this.

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is part of bash that is run after every command you run, which allows you to do cool things like [keeping track of how many correct bash commands you've typed in a row](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434409/make-a-bash-ps1-that-counts-streak-of-correct-commands), in addition to our use here of continually redefining our title.

`$TERM` is an environment variable which for me is either set to "screen" (or something like "screen-256color") when in tmux or to "xterm" when using MobaXterm. We check for this because otherwise your `$PS1` is essentially double-printed when not in tmux.

The `dynamic_title` must be in single quotes, otherwise it will be defined when you source your `~/.bashrc` and not be dynamic. However, you need it to be defined at some point or else your window will be renamed literally `${USER:0:3}@${PWD:${#PWD}<15?0:(-15)}`. This is what `eval` does, creating a string that is literally what you want the window title to be. Then we just give that string to `settitle()`, wrapped in double quotes so spaces work correctly.